# Is Gazebo site down?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

Is Gazebo site down?

I can't enter the site.

[www.gazebosim.org](http://www.gazebosim.com)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89041/is-gazebo-site-down?/) by [Park](https://answers.ros.org/users/2931/park/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like it's up to me. For questions like this you can always check a site like:

http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com

---

Originally posted by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) with karma: 549 on 2013-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Park](https://answers.ros.org/users/2931/park/) on 2013-10-09**:
Thanks Skiesel. Now the website works.